# How to load local svg file for use in firefox addon?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, firefox, firefox-addon

I have a local svg file: `image.svg`

I am able to change `<img id="image" src="notimage.png">` to `<img id="image" src="image.svg">` via firefox addon.

However, it does not appear. I assume this is because the `image.svg` isn't loaded properly.

Please help me display `image.svg` properly.

Comment: `local svg file` what do you mean by "local" ... on your computer in some random location?

Comment: @Bravo in the same folder as the addon of course

Comment: right, so it's part of the add-on - that's more useful to know than "a local svg file" - at least you did that right - you probably need to use [browser.extensions.getUrl](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/extension/getURL) to get the correct url of the packaged svg

Comment: oops, it's [runtime.getURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/getURL) now